# Registering Controller in Service Provider in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, github, laravel-5, packagist

I am trying to understand the **packages** in **laravel** which I should be able to upload to **github** subsequently.

I got everything working except for the controller of my package, h*aven't worked on views yet*.
But I am getting the following error when I visit my localhost website `http:\guam.dev\people`

```
ReflectionException

Class Dashboard does not exist
```

This is my Directory structure.

```
laravel
-vendor
--student
---people
----composer.json
----src
-----PeopleServiceProvider.php
-----Controllers
------SuperAdmin
-------Dashboard.php
-----Routes
-----Views
```

This is my PeopleServiceProvider.php

```
namespace Student\People;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PeopleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        include __DIR__ . '/Routes/routes.php';
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/Views/SuperAdmin/Dashboard', 'People');
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->make('Student\People\Dashboard');
    }
}
```

Controller file : Dashboard.php

```
namespace Student\People;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class Dashboard extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('app');
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? I am following an old tutorial, but there isn't much explanation about controllers there.

Comment: why are you using the vendor folder? that is usually used for packages

Comment: It is a package, that's why I need service provider for a controller. My bad, I should have mentioned it in the original post. Let me do it right now.

Comment: Honestly I still don't understand the reason why you're modifying the vendor folder... Anyway which `5.x` is this?

Comment: @Fahmi Aren't packages supposed to go in to the vendor folder ? That is where composer will download them from github anyway. It is laravel 5.4. I hope you understand what I Am asking here.

Comment: Okay so you're building a composer package with Laravel support, right?

Comment: @Fahmi Yes Exactly.